# react-redux's dispatch fails to call appropriately in the form handling function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, single-page-application

I'm building cryptocurrency exchange app with third party api. My problem arises from the calling `store.dispatch()` from the `ConvertForm` component. Although, i will still use `connect()`, but i want to test the form handing life-cycle first. Anytime i click submit button with `handleCryptoSubmit()` event handle, the `store.dispatch()` supposed to call the `fetchCryptoToCurrencyBegin()` (only using this for texting), the functon supposed to change the reduce's state's loading property to `TRUE`. On submiting the form, after verification of the inputs, the `fetchCryptoToCurrencyBegin()` do not alter the loading property to `True` until I change the either of the value of `cryptoCode` form field or `currencyCode` form field again. And it will automatically call the `fetchCryptoToCurrencyBegin()` without click submit after the change.

I have check my `onChangeHandle()` if i make any mistake in the form handling function and the reduce and action codes. Everything seems to be working fine. Although i'm new to react, i have search internet for possible answers without any success. I have used `setState()` to fetch api data, it works on first try. I don't think connecting the component to redux through mapdispatch will work either. My problem is react-redux

```js
///this is my inner state for form validation
 this.state={
   cryptoToCurrencyState:{
                quantityAmount: {
                    figureAmount: null,
                    amountErrorMessage: '',
                    validInput: true,
                    validForSubmit: false
                },

                cryptoCode: { 
                    tokenCode: '',
                },
                currencyCode: {
                    nationalCode: '',

                }
              },
}
```

```js
/// this is my form field change handler.

 // for reusing the targetProperty logic
    targetPropertyUtility = (target) => {
        let objectTarget;
        if (target.name === 'quantityAmount'){
            return objectTarget = 'figureAmount';
        }else if (target.name === 'cryptoCode'){
            return objectTarget = 'tokenCode';
        }
        return objectTarget = 'nationalCode';

    }; 

 handleCryptoChange = (e) => { 
          const regexp = new RegExp(`^-?[0-9]*$`);
          const target = e.target;
          e.persist();
          // check above arror function to understand targetPropertyUtility
          let targetProperty = this.targetPropertyUtility(target)
          if (target.name === 'quantityAmount' && !regexp.test(target.value)){
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                cryptoToCurrencyState:{
                    ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState,
                    [target.name]: {
                        ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState[target.name],
                        [targetProperty] : target.value,
                        amountErrorMessage: 'input only valid number',
                        validInput: false,
                        validForSubmit: false
                        } 
                }
                });
        }else if(target.name === 'quantityAmount' && regexp.test(target.value)){
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                cryptoToCurrencyState:{
                    ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState,
                    [target.name]: {
                        ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState[target.name],
                        [targetProperty] : target.value,
                        amountErrorMessage: null,
                        validInput: true,
                        validForSubmit: true

                        } 
                }
                });
        }else{
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                cryptoToCurrencyState:{
                    ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState,
                    [target.name]: {
                        ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState[target.name],
                        [targetProperty] : target.value,
                    }
                },

            });

        }

    };
```

```js
///this is my onSubmit hander

// this event handle the submit of cryptocurrency to national currency

     handleCryptoSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const {cryptoToCurrencyState} = this.state;
         const {quantityAmount}= cryptoToCurrencyState;

         lauch action thunk if the form is valid
         /// if form is not valid, validation error will be displayed and the action thunk will be prevented
         /// There will be main error display to show the form is not valid

        if(quantityAmount.validForSubmit){
          /// action for testing
            store.dispatch(fetchCryptoToCurrencyBegin());

        }else if(!quantityAmount.figureAmount){
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                cryptoToCurrencyState:{
                    ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState,
                    quantityAmount: {
                        ...this.state.cryptoToCurrencyState.quantityAmount,
                        amountErrorMessage: 'The field is required',
                        validInput: false,
                        validForSubmit: false
                        },

                }
                });
            }
```

I want the `store.dispatch()` to trigger `fetchCryptoToCurrencyBegin()` on the verification on the form field. Thanks.

Comment: First i ask because you havent explicitly mentioned where store object ia coming from? Did you export it from your store definition page?? And Ive had so much trouble in this area simply because my react and redux version were in conflict, first make sure its not a version conflict issue before proceeding!!

Comment: Yes I imported the store object into the component. I will check the the version now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using connect on the component. Thus, store.dispatch() will not effectively work in a component if the component is not connected to the HOC connect/Provider of the react-redux.